# Splitting code into different Javascript files

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am working on a Javascript/HTML5 canvas based game and so far my JS code is 1200+ lines long.
I am using lots of Objects and lots of different function as well so a question came to my mind.

Is there any possible way to have separate objects in separate JS files and a main file where I would refer to those separated objects in their own JS files? I just want to keep my code simple cause it is starting to look a little messy.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Like akluth said, you can use external libraries to "load" your external Javascript files.

If you don't wish to use any of these then it's the gool'ol fashioned JS way: You include all your external files like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="external/file.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/) for this - it allows you to seperate your code into [AMD modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) which can be easily used accross your project.

To have optimized and minified code in your production environment you can use [r.js, the requireJS optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) which allows you to concat all your modules into one minified and uglified file.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes. You can place each object and its properties and methods in its own file loading each file as Jarrod suggests.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="external/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="external/obj1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="external/obj2.js"></script>
```

where 'external' is a directory in the same folder as your HTML file.

Comment: Wasn't "external" obvious? This would be better suited as a comment under my answer rather than duplicating the answer.